# R - write.table() creates table that isn't read properly by fread()

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table in R that I'm trying to write out to a .txt file, and then input back into R.

It's sizeable table of 6.5M observations and 20 variables, so I want to use fread().

When I use

```
write.table(data, file = "data.txt")
```

a table of about 2.2GB is written in data.txt. In manually inspecting it, I can see that there are column names, that it's separated by " ", and that there are quotes on character variables. So everything should be fine.

However,

```
data <- fread("data.txt")
```

returns a data.table of 6.5M observations and 1 variable. OK, maybe for some reason fread() isn't automatically understanding the separator string:

```
data <- fread("data.txt", sep = " ")
```

All the data is in the proper variables now, but

- R has added an unnecessary row-number column
- in one (only one) of my columns all NAs have been replaced by 9218868437227407266
- All variable names are missing

Maybe fread() isn't recognizing the header, somehow.

```
data <- fread("data.txt", sep = " ", header = T)
```

Now my first set of observations is my column names. Not very useful.

I'm completely baffled. Does anyone understand what's happening here?

EDIT:

`row.names = F` solved the names problem, thanks Ananda Mahto.

Ran

```
datasub <- data[runif(1000,1,6497651), ]
write.table(datasub, file = "datasub.txt", row.names = F)
fread("datasub.txt")
```

`fread()` seems to work fine for the smaller dataset.

EDIT:

Here is the subset of data I created above:

https://github.com/cbcoursera1/ExploratoryDataAnalysisProject2/blob/master/datasub.txt

This data comes from the National Emissions Inventory (NEI) and is made available by the EPA. More information is available here:

http://www.epa.gov/ttn/chief/eiinformation.html

EDIT:

I can no longer reproduce this issue. It may be that `row.names = F` solved the issue, or possibly restarting R/clearing my environment/something random fixed the problem.

Comment: For the row-number column problem, add `row.names = FALSE` to your `write.table`. For the other things, can you try to create a small dataset that demonstrates the same problems you're presently having?

Comment: `row.names = F` solved the names problem.

Ran 

`datasub <- data[runif(1000,1,6497651), ]`       
`write.table(datasub, file = "datasub.txt", row.names = F)`     
`fread("datasub.txt")`    

`fread()` seems to work fine for the smaller dataset.